# line break for long captions in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

So the problem I am facing now is that whenever a line breaks due to long caption, the second line always start at a tiny indent further than the first line. I have attached the image of it as well as the code. Btw, I have no knowledge of coding and I just used the default latex file given by the university. [image]

```
%======================= Table of Contents =========================

\setlength{\parskip}{0pt} 
\newpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents

%===================== List of Figures ======================

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures

\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}

\small

\setlength{\headheight}{12pt}
\pagestyle{plain}

%=====================List of Tables ========================
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt} 
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
\listoftables
```

Comment: Welcome, the code you posted is very confusing, unfortunately, it doesn't  give any clue why the behaviour you are describing is happening. Please provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that?lq=1).

Comment: If the university provided the document class, they went to a lot of effort to create that effect.  However you can always replace \l@figure with, say, the default from article.cls.